# Macro para filtrar campo de tabla dinamica conectada a un cubo

Tags: vba, tabla-dinámica

Tengo una tabla dinámica que esta conectada a la base de datos de SAP de mi empresa, tengo entendido que es una conexión mediante cubo.
Sin embargo, estoy creando una macro para que me cambie los filtros en funcion a cambios en el valor de una celda, si esta cambia, se debe cambiar el filtro. Pero me arroja error en la instruccion .currentpage

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F1")) Is Nothing Then
```

'En base al campo Nombre de la Tabla dinámica:

```
 With PivotTables("Tabla dinámica5").CubeFields(4).PivotFields( _
 "[Clientes].[Nombre].[Nombre]")
```

'Limpiar todos los filtros

```
.ClearAllFilters
```

'Filtrar por el valor de la celda F2

```
On Error Resume Next
.CurrentPage = Range("F2").Value
              
End With
End If

End Sub
```

Si realizo una grabación de la macro, para seleccionar un cliente, el código que me entrega es el siguiente:

```
'ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabla dinámica5").CubeFields(4).EnableMultiplePageItems = True
'  ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabla dinámica5").PivotFields( _
'  "[Clientes].[Nombre].[Nombre]").VisibleItemsList = Array( _
'  "[Clientes].[Nombre].&[ABAST. DEL COMERCIO ADELCO LTD]")
```

pero la instruccion Visibleitemslist al parecer no la considera VBA para seleccionar un dato, o quizas ma falta la instruccion para deseleccionar todos los clientes, y luego seleccionar el cliente especifico.

Agradezco su ayuda

Mil gracias

Answer (score 2):

Este código te filtraría esa tabla por el valor que hay en el rango F2 de la hoja activa:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabla dinámica5").CubeFields(4).EnableMultiplePageItems = True
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabla dinámica5").PivotFields( _
"[Clientes].[Nombre].[Nombre]").VisibleItemsList = Array( _
"[Clientes].[Nombre].&[" & Range("F2") & "]")
```

Si por otro lado, quisieras filtrar varios items a la vez, pongamos el rango de `F2:F(útlima fila con datos)` tendrías que hacer esto:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabla dinámica5").CubeFields(4).EnableMultiplePageItems = True
    Dim arrFiltro As Variant
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HojaConLosFiltros") 'Cambia eso
        'esto cuenta la última fila con datos en la columna F
        Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
        'dimensionamos un array tan grande como las celdas con filtros
        Dim arrFiltro(1 To LastRow - 1)
        Dim i As Long
        'recorremos el array construyendo los filtros, uno por "fila" del array
        For i = 1 To UBound(arrFiltro)
            arrFiltro(i) = "[Clientes].[Nombre].&[" & .Cells(i + 1, "F") & "]"
        Next i
    End With
    'le damos el array lleno de filtros a la tabla dinámica para que lo aplique
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabla dinámica5").PivotFields( _
    "[Clientes].[Nombre].[Nombre]").VisibleItemsList = arrFiltro
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Hola, y si alguno de esos filtros no existe que pasa?